# How do I clone an earlier/older version of C into my latest visual studio? (pics included)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

[image: what pops up when I try to clone git project to visual studio]

I've tried clicking upgrade and no upgrade with the options in the image, but none of them worked.

Thank u for any help !

Comment: YMMV but I always recreate projects from scratch when upgrading Visual Studio. The auto upgrade is too flaky in my experience.

Comment: Note: If you've got this issue regularly, you may want to take a look at CMake. Not only would this allow you to set up multiple solutions for different msvc toolsets in parallel, but it would also allow you to create makefiles for building the project on Linux, should you feel like it (the code still needs to be Linux-compatible of course).

Comment: Are you using C or C++? They are different. Even if the Windows SDK version is updated, some functions  are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Upgrade reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrading-projects-from-earlier-versions-of-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170) carefully. When upgrading the project, you need to download the related SDK and toolset in visual studio installer. Automatic upgrade does not help much. I recommend you rebuild the project manually.